# How many bits are there in a nibble?

Tags: binary

binary question :)

Comment: Pointless question, ask Google not Stack Overflow

Comment: @jjrv, An excellent question actually!!!

Comment: Quibbles about nibbles make me giggle.

Comment: It's great that there are exactly *4* comments to this question!  Oh wait ... crap!

Comment: There are only 10 types of people in the world, those who understand binary and those who don't...
Now the comments ain't a nibble no more...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043/introduce-a-general-reference-close-reason

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer is 4 bits. 2 nibbles make a byte.

[See here](http://www.geneziegler.com/clocktower/DrSeuss.html) for a cute poem.

Comment: I take it that's a poke at Fox in Socks? :)

Comment: The page that seems to be from (http://people.cornell.edu/pages/elz1/clocktower/DrSeuss.html) says "Reprint or repost only with permission".

Comment: @Andrew's link seems long dead, here's the closest I found: http://www.geneziegler.com/clocktower/DrSeuss.html

Answer (score 15):

Four

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble

> In computing, a nibble (often nybble or nyble to match the vowels of byte) is a four-bit aggregation, or half an octet.

Answer (score 5):

0b100 bits, actually.

Answer (score 2):

I always understood a nybble to be 4 bits.  Spelling intentional as a nybble was half a byte.

Answer (score 2):

[A nibble (often, nybble) is the computing term for a four-bit aggregation, or half an octet (an octet being an 8-bit byte).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble)

Answer (score 1):

4 bits.  But I remember it being called a nybble instead of nibble, like byte versus bite.

Answer (score 0):

4 bits = 1 nibble

8 bits = 1 byte

Answer (score 0):

A nibble is normally bits BUT can refer to 2-7 bits, with 1 bit being a bit and 8 becoming a byte.

Answer (score 0):

A nibble has 4 bits (although it doesn't have to).

That also means that when you view a byte's value in hex-notation, one hex digit corresponds to one nibble. That's one reason why going from hex to binary is much easier than from decimal to binary.

Answer (score 0):

a Nybble or nibble is 4 bits. Early compter graphics used 4 bits of data fro color. as memory was precious two pixels were stored in one byte, a upper nibble and a lower nibble.